# How to include WooCommerce conditional tags in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to use the conditional tag `is_product()` from the WooCommerce plugin so my custom plugin only loads in the script if the user is at a product page on the front-end.

Additionally, I don't want the plugin to break if WooCommerce is not installed on the website.

My current code:

```php
if ( !is_admin() && is_product() ) {
    function add_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/main.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script' );
```

This doesn't work at the moment since it can't find the conditional tag `is_product()`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I don't want the plugin to break if Woocommerce is not installed on the website."* Your main plugin file should start with:

```php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// Check if WooCommerce is active
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) exit; // Exit if WC not active
```

---

Loads the script if the user is at a product page, use:

```php
function add_script() {
    // is_admin() - Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.
    // is_product() - Returns true on a single product page.
    if ( !is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/main.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script' );
```